# How to get an XPath from selenium webelement or from lxml?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, html-parsing, lxml

I am using selenium and I need to find the XPaths of some selenium web elements.

For example:

```
import selenium.webdriver
driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()

element  = driver.find_element_by_xpath(<some_xpath>)
elements = element.find_elements_by_xpath(<some_relative_xpath>)

for e in elements:
    print e.get_xpath()
```

I know I can't get the XPath from the element itself, but is there a nice way to get it anyway?

I tried using lxml to parse the HTML, but it doesn't recognize the XPath, `<some_xpath>`, I passed, even though `driver.find_element_by_xpath(<some_xpath>)` **did** manage to find that element.

Comment: Are you trying to find an element from the xpath or are you trying to generate the xpath given an element? The beginning seems to suggest the latter but the end of your question suggests the former. If it is the former you could provide the xpath you are trying and potentially the html/xml snippet?

Comment: You cannot generate an xpath from the element since there are multiple ways to find an element by xpath.

Comment: I want to find the xpath of a given element. I know there are multiple xpath representation for a given element, but any representation is fine by me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`lxml` can auto-generate an **absolute** xpath for you using [`getpath()`](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#generating-xpath-expressions) method.

Example (using [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org) main page, getting xpath expression for the logo):

```
import urllib2
from lxml import etree

data = urllib2.urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org")
tree = etree.parse(data)
element = tree.xpath('//div[@id="p-logo"]/a')[0]
print tree.getpath(element)
```

Prints:

```
/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/a
```

Answer (score 0):

Im late but hopefully this will help someone. Here is the function I wrote to recursively find the xpath. It is a bit slow on larger webpages because of how many elements it has to look up but it works great!

```
def get_xpath(self, el: WebElement, xpath: str = ""):
        if el.tag_name == "html":
            return "/html" + xpath
        
        str = el.tag_name
        parent = el.find_element("xpath", "..")
        children = parent.find_elements("xpath", "*")
        index = 0
        for child in children:
            if child.tag_name == el.tag_name:
                index += 1
                if child == el:
                    elem_index = index
        if index > 1:
            str += f"[{elem_index}]"
        str = "/" + str + xpath
        return self.get_xpath(el = parent, xpath = str)
```