# How to translate a BeautifulSoup element to xpath?

Tags: python, xpath, beautifulsoup

For example:

```
html = "
<ul>
     <li class="item-0"><a href="link1.html">first item</a></li>
     <li class="item-1"><a href="link2.html">second item</a></li>
     <li class="item-inactive"><a href="link3.html">third item</a></li>
     <li class="item-1"><a href="link4.html">fourth item</a></li>
     <li class="item-0"><a href="link5.html">fifth item</a>
</ul>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
item_0 = soup.select_one('ul li.item-0')
```

Is there a function like `soup_to_xpath(item_0)` that can translate `item_0` to `'/html/body/ul/li[5]'` or something like this?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no possibility to work with `XPath` in `bs4`.

Provided `CSS` selector could be "translated" into `XPath` as:

```
//ul/li[@class="item-0"]
```

or

```
//li[.="fifth element"]
```

You can use below code:

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector # You might need to run "pip install cssselect"

sel = CSSSelector('ul li.item-0')
sel.path
```

Output:

```
"descendant-or-self::ul/descendant-or-self::*/li[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' item-0 ')]"
```

Comment: I jsut want to get xpath. What does "Provided CSS selector could be "translated" into XPath" mean?

Comment: `'ul li.item-0'` is a `CSS` selector. Do you want to use `BeautifulSoup` to generate `XPath` or any other automation tool to generate it? Clarify your issue

Comment: "Do you want to use BeautifulSoup to generate XPath or any other automation tool to generate it?"  This is exactly what I want...

Comment: You can try to use `lxml.etree` (http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) to generate absolute `XPath` expression as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24411765/how-to-get-an-xpath-from-selenium-webelement-or-from-lxml

Comment: `tree.getpath(element)` Here the element seems to be a lxml object, I want to translate a bs element to xpah, the same demand as the quizzer.

Answer (score 0):

lxml use cssselect module to perform such task:

```
In [1]: from cssselect import GenericTranslator, SelectorError

In [2]: expression = GenericTranslator().css_to_xpath('ul li.item-0')

In [3]: expression
Out[3]: "descendant-or-self::ul/descendant-or-self::*/li[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' item-0 ')]"
```